# Почему это причастие?

Tags: морфология

Современный орфографический словарь считает слово **"сбалансированный"** (например, "сбалансированное питание") причастием и говорит его писать с "н" в краткой форме. Почему? Ведь слово можно заменить синонимом - ***корректное***, наиболее ***правильное***. К тому же можно подставить "очень" и образовать краткую форму: ***очень сбалансированное*** питание, такое питание куда ***сбалансированней***.

Answer (score 1):

**Это мое решение задачи**

**1. Что считает толковый словарь Кузнецова?**

**СБАЛАНСИРОВАННЫЙ**, -ая, -ое. Книжн. 1. С правильным соотношением между доходами и расходами (о бюджете). С. бюджет. 2. С правильным соотношением частей, элементов чего-л. С. собачий корм. С-ое развитие экономики. <Сбалансированно, нареч. Экономика развивается с.

Это прилагательное, есть определительное наречие.

**2. Что считает словарь РАН?**

сбалансированный; кр. ф. -ан, -ана

Это краткая форма причастия, краткой формы «сбалансированна» нет.

Смотрим соответствующий глагол в толковом словаре

**СБАЛАНСИРОВАТЬ**, -рую, -руешь; св. (чем). 1. Установить равновесие. С. на краю пропасти. С. рукой. С. всем телом. 2. что. Привести в правильное соотношение. С. питание, диету. С. бюджет. С. развитие региона.

**3. Читаем ответы Грамоты.ру**

**Вопрос № 293121.** Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужно писать одну "н" или две? Предложение "Важно питаться сбалансироваННо".

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка.** Правильно с двумя н, т. к. это наречие, образованное от слова, в котором пишется два н – сбалансированный. Ср. с **причастием**: *звучание идеально **сбалансировано дирижером**.*

**Вопрос № 267370.** Очень прошу - ответьте, на свой предыдущий вопрос я так и не получила ответа. Корректно ли словосочетание "максимально сбалансированный"?

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка.** Это корректное сочетание.

**4. Вывод**

(1) Есть прилагательное «сбалансированный», а также наречие «сбалансированно»;  есть сочетания «максимально сбалансированный, максимально сбалансированно».

(2) Но у этого прилагательного нет краткой формы «сбалансированна».

**P.S.** Я отвечу только на комментарии, уточняющие и улучшающие мой  ответ. Пожалуйста, не пишите  под моим ответом ничего другого. Картинки тоже рисовать не надо.

Comment: **Запрашивать** уточнение или предлагать улучшение. Ну и конструктивная критика.

Comment: КОНСТРУКТИВНЫЙ, 2. Создающий основу для дальнейшей работы; плодотворный, результативный. К-ое предложение. К-ая разработка. Встреча в верхах была конструктивной. К-ая критика.  Это ОЦЕНОЧНОЕ понятие: конструктивное для вас неконструктивно для меня.

Comment: Ну да, создаёт основу для того, чтобы вы исправили и улучшили ответ. Довольно объективное слово. Ну и должно быть конструктивным для меня, не будет же каждый спрашивать, конструктивно ли, перед тем как критиковать. Вам лишь бы увильнуть, чтобы отмахнуться от всей критики. А защищаться вообще не умеете. Некоторые здесь даже неправду умело защищают.

Comment: Вот и пишите им, какие они молодцы. Ну и голосуйте за них...

Comment: Ну а у меня только проблемы из-за этого. Ещё бы за неправду голосовать...

Comment: До свидания....

Comment: Не бойтесь правды. Это луч света, освещающий тьму вашего разума.

Comment: Хорош уже здесь мусорить...

Comment: Сами вы мусорите. Пишу вам художественное... :(