# Слово "определяющий" — это причастие или прилагательное?

Tags: морфология, прилагательные, причастия

**С одной стороны,** во многих учебных материалах слово "определяющий" считается **причастием** по глаголу "определять" (то, что определяет).

**С другой стороны,** у него есть собственная **словарная статья**, и там указаны **синонимы**: *основной, наиболее существенный, решающий.*

И тогда здесь можно увидеть явное сближение **с прилагательным.**

**ОПРЕДЕЛЯЮЩИЙ**, -ая, -ее; Книжн. Основной, наиболее существенный, решающий. О-ие силы демократического движения. О. момент матча. О-ее направление науки. О-ая роль экономических условий. Практическое применение должно быть определяющим в решении вопроса.

Comment: переставьте слова: направление науки определяющий. Практическое применение должно быть определяющим в решении вопроса - тут уж точно причастие.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий, но я не уверена. Но чтобы окончательно не согласиться с вашим замечанием, надо подумать... Вы не могли записать ваше мнение в поле ответа?  Возможные решения: (1) всегда прилагательное; (2) всегда  причастие; (3) прилагательное или причастие (зависит от грамматики предложения).

Comment: Sharon, конечно, это слово, как и многие другие, может выполнять функции и причастия, и прилагательного в зависимости от вкладываемого смысла. [ОПРЕДЕЛЯ́ЮЩИЙ](https://sinonim.org/t/определяющий):  **2.** *в значении прилагательного*  Основной, наиболее существенный, решающий. *И все же в самых крупных, определяющих чертах метод остается единым.* Бек, Почтовая проза.

Comment: Спасибо, вы тоже не хотите ответить в поле ответа?  Такой простой вопрос, что и отвечать-то не о чем?  Надо хотя бы примеры привести с двумя вариантами.

Comment: Сейчас неохота и некогда выискивать. Когда оно стоит после определяемого слова и имеет зависимые, тогда явно причастие: *Что-то, определяющее что-то.*

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение. А что,  оборотов на основе прилагательных не бывает?  Например:   Я обратила внимание на его волосы, явно крашеные.

Comment: Бывает, но мы же говорим о конкретном слове и его влиянии на другие. И действительно, нужно смотреть примеры.

Comment: Я задала вопрос в связи с тем, что не очень поняла смысл вопроса о сочетаниях. Там автор в чем-то сомневается, но в чем? И тогда я задумалась о вопросе в общем плане.

Comment: @Sharon есть способ однозначного определения причастия или прилагательного?

Comment: Как однозначно их различить?  Есть признаки адъективации причастий, эта тема на форуме часто обсуждалась. Признаки можно посмотреть  здесь  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474335/Как-отличить-причастие-от-прилагательного   Вот еще тема https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474378/Почему-это-причастие

Answer (score 2):

*Определять* + суффикс причастия -ющ-, значит по умолчанию причастие.

Есть ли условия для перехода в отглаг. прилагательные?

Предположим, рассматриваем в контексте "*определяющее направление в науке*". Пробуем заменить на
"*направление, которое определяет науку*" - как мне кажется, смысл меняется: *направление* становится самым важным, тогда как "*определяющих направлений*" может быть несколько. Получается, что отглаг. прилагательное... правильно? :)

А вот если бы было "определяющий голос" (в голосовании), то "голос, который определяет" вполне сохраняло бы смысл, и это было бы причастием.

---

Наверное, сложность из-за того, что исходный глагол без приставки и несовершенного вида. Если был спорный был суффикс -Н-/-НН-, то однозначно было бы отгл. прилагательное (если без зависимых слов). С такими исходными глаголами очень сложно применять признак замены на глагол.

Сравните:

"груженый вол". Пробуем заменить: "вол, которого грузили". Разница есть, но она достаточно тонкая.

А если исходный глагол совершенного вида, то проще.

"зачитанная книга" -> "книга, которую зачитали", причастие.

"взволнованное лицо" -> "лицо, которое взволновали", так не говорят, отгл. прилагательное.

---

Как мне кажется, c чисто практической точки зрения в этом конкретном случае большой разницы (отглаг. прилагательное или причастие) нет, ведь они пишутся одинаково, как и их краткие формы. Ошибки могу быть с суффиксами -Н-/-НН-/-ЕН-/-ЕНН-, тогда это действительно важно. А так, не все ли равно?

Comment: Спасибо вам за ответ и внимание к теме (голос от меня). Вопрос непростой, я попробую дать свой ответ.

Comment: Спасибо за хороший вопрос. Я обновил ответ и расписал немного поподробнее свое понимание, надеюсь, оно имеет связь с реальностью :)

Comment: Связь с реальностью хороша видна на примерах из Карты слов:  там указаны предложения, в которых ясно просматривается ситуация. И тогда без труда можно определить значение слова как прилагательного (важный, существенный) или как причастия (который определяет, решает что-либо).  Зачем нам это нужно. Ошибиться можно не только в выборе Н/НН, но в стилистике, в пунктуации, в наречиях степени, которые можно отнести преимущественно к качественному прилагательному.  https://kartaslov.ru/предложения-со-словом/определяющий

Answer (score 0):

1. В Большом толковом словаре Кузнецова дается отдельная статья для **прилагательного,** но не для причастия. (Причастие — это форма глагола.)
2. Надо сделать проверку **по грамматике.**

**[Метасловарь](https://gramota.ru/meta/opredelyat).** В полной таблице грамматики указаны две возможные формы  причастия для глагола ***определить***: определивший и определенный и три формы для глагола ***определять.*** Действительное,    ***определя́ющий,***    определя́вший. Страдательное,   определя́емый.

3. Итак, возможны разные варианты, и  нужно смотреть по глаголу ***определять*** в  [Большом толковом словаре](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C&mode=slovari&l=1&dicts%5B%5D=42) (там 6 значений).
4. **Вывод**

Слово ***определяющий*** может быть (1) причастием или (2) прилагательным с указанными в словаре (для прилагательного) значениями. В этом случае имеет место  **переход** причастия в прилагательное.. В остальных значениях глагола ***определять*** это **причастие**.